# adding jpeg image to pdf using xobject

Tags: image, pdf, adobe, intersystems-cache

Enhancing in-house/internal software, that creates very basic PDF files, to handle images. Using JPEG seems to be the easiest place. Inserting JPEG image into Xobject stream by opening Image file and performing Reads from image file and Writes into PDF file. However, when viewing PDF file, getting errors on Image length. Appears PDF JPEG Image stream contents is not the exact same format as the Image file itself. I'm not using any PDF development tools to build the PDF file, just developing code myself to do this.

Does anyone know exactly how to add JPEG image file contents into Xobject stream? Appears to be or needs to be a conversion or something.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Short answer is that a JPEG image should translate fairly readily to a PDF stream. You will need to dissect the JPEG header to correctly set ColorSpace. Width, Height, BitsPerComponent, and DCTDecode filter in the stream dictionary.

Comment: Thanks @dwarring! I have a google cloud folder link https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1LHRs1_mf3Xq_eHA-HLE17rW4k58sSNDN?usp=sharing that contains the generated PDF file and the JPEG Image file. I'm running my PDF file thru PDF-Online.com ANALYZE AND REPAIR PDF FILE and getting the following errors listed below. Any idea why? Errors:

Open file.
Analyze Objects.
0x80410308 - E - The "endobj" keyword is missing.
    - Object No.: 6
    - File: JDCBRST_011.PDF
0x80410308 - E - The "endobj" keyword is missing.
    - Object No.: 6
    - File: JDCBRST_011.PDF